# The vectors are orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $(a_{ij})$ be a skew-symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix (i.e., $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$  for all $i, j$).

Let $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ be smooth functions of a parameter $s$ satisfying the differential equations
$$v'_i= \sum_{j=1}^3 a_{ij} v_j$$

for i = $1, 2$ and $3$, and suppose that for some parameter value $s_0$ the
vectors $v_1(s_0)$, $v_2(s_0)$ and $v_3(s_0)$ are orthonormal. Show that the
vectors $v_1(s), v_2(s)$ and $v_3(s)$ are orthonormal for all values of $s$.

I am facing difficulties. Any hints how to show that  the
vectors $v_1(s), v_2(s)$ and $v_3(s)$ are orthonormal for all values of $s$?

**EDIT Nr.1**:

$\frac{d}{ds}(\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>) = \frac{d}{ds}(v_i(s)^t v_j(s) 
 )=(v_i(s)^t)' v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t (v_j(s))' \\= \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{jk}v_k(s) $

Any ideas how I can continue?

$$$$

**EDIT Nr.2:**

We have $$\frac{d}{ds}(\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>) = \frac{d}{ds}(v_i(s)^t v_j(s) 
 )=(v_i(s)^t)' v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t (v_j(s))' \\= \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{jk}v_k(s) =\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)-v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{kj}v_k(s)$$

It is $$v_k(s)^tv_j(s)=v_k(s)v_j(s)^t$$ right?

Therefore we have $$\frac{d}{ds}(\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>) =\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)-v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{kj}v_k(s)=\sum_{k=1}^3 [a_{ik} v_k(s) v_j(s)^t-a_{kj} v_i(s)^t v_k(s)]=\sum_{k=1}^3 v_k(s)[a_{ik} v_j(s)^t-a_{kj} v_i(s)^t]$$

What can we do next?

Comment: Can you write down the solution to the system of differential equations you are given in terms of the matrix involved?

Comment: I added what I did so far. Can you look at it and tell if it is correct and what we can do next? @uniquesolution

Comment: Sorry, too complicated.

Comment: Your argument uses subscripts to denote both vector components and indices on your triple of vector-valued functions, so unfortunately much of what you write doesn't make sense. Instead, start by differentiating the inner product $f_{ij}(s) := \langle v_{i}(s), v_{j}(s)\rangle$ to get $f'_{ij}(s) = 2\langle v_{i}(s), v'_{j}(s)\rangle$, then write the latter (perhaps using _superscripts_ as indices) as$$2\sum_{k,\ell=1}^{3} a_{k\ell} v_{i}^{k}(s) v_{j}^{\ell}(s)$$and use skew-symmetry to deduce $f_{ij}$ is constant.

Comment: How do we get $$f'_{ij}(s) = 2\langle v_{i}(s), v'_{j}(s)\rangle
$$ when we differentiate $$f_{ij}(s) := \langle v_{i}(s), v_{j}(s)\rangle
$$ ? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: That's the product rule for dot products, except in haste I gave the rule for the special case $i = j$; the correct general formula is$$\frac{d}{ds}\langle v_{i}(s), v_{j}(s)\rangle = \langle v_{i}'(s), v_{j}(s)\rangle + \langle v_{i}(s), v_{j}'(s)\rangle.$$

Comment: So we get $$\frac{d}{ds}(\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>) = \frac{d}{ds}(v_i(s)^t v_j(s) 
 )=(v_i(s)^t)' v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t (v_j(s))' \\= \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)+v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{jk}v_k(s) =\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik} v_k(s)^t v_j(s)-v_i(s)^t \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{kj}v_k(s)
$$ or not? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: You're still using subscripts as vector components. :) Omitting dependence on $s$, the derivative comes out to$$v_{i}^{t}A^{t}v_{j} + v_{i}^{t}Av_{j} = \sum_{k,\ell} v_{i}^{k}(A_{\ell k} + A_{k\ell})v_{j}^{\ell}.$$

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got this relation? I am confused... @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Just had a close look at your notation. Are you sure your differential equation is indexed correctly? The usual system of ODEs for your conclusion (see Pavel's answer) is $v_{i}' = Av_{i}$, or writing $v_{ik}$ for the $k$th component of $v_{i}$,$$(v_{ik})' = \sum_{j=1}^{3} a_{jk} v_{ij}.$$ This is not the same thing as $v_{i}' = \sum_{j} a_{ij} v_{j}$, which in components reads$$v_{ik}' = \sum_{j=1}^{3} a_{ij} v_{jk}.$$ Apologies if my earlier comments sent you in the wrong direction.

Comment: In my book the formula is $$v_i '=\sum_{j=1}^3 a_{ij}v_j$$ @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: If that equation were correct, then introducing the $3 \times 3$ matrix $V$ whose $i$th row is $v_{i}^{t}$, the differential equation would read $V' = AV$. The matrix whose entries are the dot products of the $v_{i}$ would be $VV^{t}$; differentiating and using the ODE would give$$(VV^{t})' = V'V^{t} + V(V')^{t} = \dots = AVV^{t} - VV^{t}A,$$which seems not automatically to be $0$. It therefore appears the equation in your book is not what the author intended. :) If instead you start from $v_{i}' = Av_{i}$, can you get things to work out?

Comment: Do we take the dot product $\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>$ or $\left< v_{ik}(s), v_{jk}(s) \right>$ ? I am a little confused about the indices... @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: My comment of October 15 ("the correct general formula...") should now be helpful. :) You can actually do the calculation without referring to components (as you were originally doing), using $v_{i}' = Av_{i}$ (and similarly for $j$), and remembering that $(Av_{i})^{t} = v_{i}^{t} A^{t} = -v_{i}^{t}A$. (My suggestions regarding components are mathematically correct, but were predicated on my mistaken assumption about the governing ODE.)

Comment: $A$ is the matrix of $a_{ij}$ ? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Yes. :) Note that you can even avoid looking at entries of $A$ by calculating "at the level of vectors and matrices" as in my preceding comment.

Comment: Do you mean the following? 

We have that $$v'_i= \sum_{j=1}^3 a_{ij} v_i \Rightarrow v_i'=Av_i$$ where $A$ is a  skew-symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix, so $A^t=-A$. 


$$\frac{d}{ds}(\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>) = \left< v_i'(s), v_j(s) \right>+\left< v_i(s), v_j'(s) \right>= \\ \left< Av_{i}(s), v_j(s) \right>+\left< v_i(s), Av_{j}(s) \right>= (Av_{i}(s))^t v_j(s) + v_i(s)^t Av_{j}(s) \\ =v_{i}(s)^{t} A^{t} v_j(s) + v_i(s)^t Av_{j}(s)=-v_{i}(s)^{t}A v_j(s) + v_i(s)^t Av_{j}(s)=0
$$

Comment: So $$\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>=c, \forall s$$ Since $$\left< v_i(s_0), v_j(s_0) \right>=0, \text{ for } i \neq j \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \left< v_i(s_0), v_j(s_0) \right>=1, \text{ for } i = j$$ 

we conclude that for each $s$ we have $$\left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>=0, \text{ for } i \neq j \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \left< v_i(s), v_j(s) \right>=1, \text{ for } i = j$$ 

Is everything correct? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Yes, that all looks perfectly correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $v_i \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, define $v \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M_{3 \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ by $v(s) = (v_1(s), v_2(s), v_3(s))^t$. The system of equations for $v$ is equivalent to the linear system $v'(s) = Av(s)$ with constant coefficients. Define also $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M_3(\mathbb{R})$ by $g(s) = v(s) v(s)^t$. The matrix $g(s)$ is then the Gram matrix for the vectors $v_1(s), v_2(s), v_3(s)$. You want to show that if $g(s_0) = I$, then $g(s) \equiv I$.

If you are familiar with matrix exponential, you can write the solution to $v'(s) = Av(s)$ as $v(s) = e^{A(s-s_0)} v(s_0)$ and then

$$ g(s) = v(s) v(s)^t = e^{A(s - s_0)} v(s_0) v(s_0)^t (e^{A(s - s_0)})^t = e^{A(s - s_0)} g(s_0) e^{A^t(s - s_0)} $$.

If $g(s_0) = I$ and $A$ is anti-symmetric, we see that $g(s) = e^{A(s - s_0)}e^{-A(s - s_0)} = I$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

If you don't want to use matrix exponentials, you can calculate

$$ g'(s) = v'(s) v(s)^t + v(s) (v'(s))^t = Av(s)v(s)^t + v(s)v(s)^tA^t = Ag(s) - g(s)A  = [A, g(s)]. $$

You can check that $g(s) \equiv I$ satisfies this equation and so, if you know that $g(s_0) = I$ for some $s_0$ then by uniqueness of solutions you must have $g(s) \equiv I$.

Comment: I added what I did so far. Can you look at it and tell if it is correct and what we can do next?

Comment: I added more details.